# Converting TIdStrings to AnsiString

Tags: c++builder, indy

I was working with some Indy classes, `TIdPOP3` and `TIdMessage`. In particular, I want to retrieve the contents of the body from a `TIdMessage`. From the documentation, `TIdMessage` has a Body property which is of type `TIdStrings`. Is there a way to convert this to `AnsiString`?

EDIT:
I am trying to print out the body I read from the `TIdMessage` and output it into a txt file, but I am doing something wrong as an empty string is outputted. Below is a sample of my code. Body is a global `AnsiString` variable and `popMssg` is a `TIdMessage` object.

```
Body = popMssg->Body->Text;     
LogMssg("Vitran code from email body: %s \n", Body.c_str());
```

This is my `LogMssg()` function, it just takes the input parameter and writes it to a txt file.

```
int MailRouter::LogMssg(char * fmt, ...)
{
    SYSTEMTIME  st;
    int         len;
    FILE *      log;
    va_list     args;
    char        logName[256], mssg[1024], dirName[64];

    GetSystemTime(&st);
    sprintf(dirName, "\\\\%s\\Logs\\MailRouter", VIP00.c_str());
    CreateDirectory(dirName, 0);
    sprintf(logName, "\\\\%s\\Logs\\MailRouter\\%04u_%02u_%02u.txt", VIP00.c_str(), st.wYear, st.wMonth, st.wDay);

    log = fopen(logName, "a");
    if(log != 0) {
        va_start(args, fmt);
        len = vfprintf(log, fmt, args);
        va_end(args);
        fclose(log);
    }

    return len;
}
```

EDIT 2: Here's a screenshot of my email. The first image is an attachment and the '10' under it is the email body I am trying to print out.
[image: Email]

Comment: Indy's documentation is quite old. The `TIdStrings` class was replaced many many years ago with the RTL's standard [`Classes::TStrings`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TStrings) class, which has a [`Text`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TStrings.Text) property that returns a `System::String` (`AnsiString` in CB2007 and earlier, `UnicodeString` in CB2009 and later). You can assign that `String` to an `AnsiString`, but why are you using `AnsiString` in modern code?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'm working with some legacy code, so I used `AnsiString` to keep things consistent. By the way, would you mind taking a look at my edit? I tried your suggestion with the Text property, but it is outputting an empty string.

Comment: It would help to see the actual email that you are loading into the `TIdMessage`. If the `TIdMessage::Body` is empty, then chances are the email is more complex than just plain text (as is often the case nowadays), and thus the text you are looking for has likely been stored as a `TIdText` object in the `TIdMessage::MessageParts`, instead of stored in the `TIdMessage::Body`. For instance, see the [HTML Messages](https://www.indyproject.org/2005/08/17/html-messages/) article in Indy's blog.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Please see my edit, I added a screenshot of the email. I think you may be right about the `TIdText` object. I saw `TIdMessage::MessageParts` in the documentation, I think I misunderstood the difference between that and `TIdMessage::Body`. I'll try that out instead!

Comment: A screenshot is not helpful, I would need to see the **raw data** of the email to see its structure. But the fact that the email has an image attached to it just enforces what I said in my earlier comment, that the email is not just plain text, so there is more processing needed to handle it, and thus `TIdMessage::Body` is not sufficient for that task.

Comment: I was able to print out the email body with the `TIdText` object in `MessageParts`. Thanks for your help Remy!